# Вышитый/вышетый

Tags: орфография

Почему пишется не *вышетый*, а *вышитый*? Мне интересно именно многоохватывающее правило.

Comment: А почему вы у своего учителя по русскому языку всё это не спрашиваете? Просто интересно. Вживую же проще спрашивать.

Comment: Вы – хорошие, мудрые совы, а это учителя – им бы после работы только отдохнуть. Кроме того, они, на самом деле, на многие из моих вопросов, в отличие от Sharon, не в состоянии ответить-таки. (С них – учителей – это и не требуется, так что я никого не осуждаю.)

Comment: А не надо после работы. Просто после урока. Ну и по чуть-чуть. Умные учителя такое очень любят, а тупые — нет.

Comment: Умных немного, по-честному.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Словоизменительная система глаголов**

Глаголы в русском языке образуют сложную систему словоизменения, которая подробно изучается в общей грамматике. Это выглядит примерно так.

Все глаголы делятся **на классы и группы**. Классификация глаголов определяется двумя **факторами**: 1) соотношение основ инфинитива и формы настоящего времени; 2) понятие **продуктивности**, то есть способности данного класса глаголов служить образцом при создании новых слов.

Глаголы с **продуктивным** соотношением основ делятся на 5 классов, а непродуктивные глаголы с индивидуальным соотношением основ делятся **на 10 групп**. Каждый класс или группа относится **к определенному** спряжению – первому или второму. Таким образом, выбор личного окончания зависит **от основы и сложился исторически.**

Приведенная **классификация глаголов** не изучается в средней школе. В школьном курсе выбор спряжения делается **упрощенным способом:** не по классам и группам, а по **формальному** признаку – определенному **глагольному суффиксу.** Глаголы, не соответствующие основному правилу, относятся **к исключениям.**

**Примечание.** Конечно, совершенно необязательно знать, к какой словоизменительной группе принадлежит глагол. Но надо хорошо понимать, что глагольный суффикс **не задает глаголу спряжение,** а всего лишь помогает определить  спряжение по формальному признаку.

Материал есть в книге **«Русская грамматика**» под ред. Шведовой и Лопатина, изд. 2-ое, 1990 г.

**О глаголе  *шить***

В глаголе выделается корень на гласную  ***ШИ***-

Глагол  ***шить***  из непродуктивного класса: III группа, 1-я подгруппа. Соотношение основ: **шить – ши-ла – ш (jу)т**,  то есть отношение гласных **[и – нуль]**. Другими словами, в неопределенной форме и форме **прошедшего времени** корневой гласный  ***И***, а в настоящем времени корневого  гласного нет, только согласный ***Ш***-

В эту подгруппу входит пять глаголов: ***бить, вить, лить, пить, шить.*** Они имеют ударные окончания I  спряжения: *шью – шьёшь – шьёт – шьём –шьёте – шьют.*

**О глаголе вышить**

Глагол ***вышить***  относится к той ж подгруппе, спряжение тоже первое, но окончания безударные: *вышью – вышьешь – вышьет – вышьем – вышьете – вышьют.*

**Правило**

Глаголы с приставкой ВЫ и без приставки относятся **к одному** спряжению. Если глагол без приставки имеет **ударные  личные** окончания, то окончания того же спряжения используются и в глаголе с приставкой ВЫ: бьёшь – выбьешь, ***шьешь – вышьешь***. Здесь можно сделать **ошибку**. Формы глаголы выбьешь, вышьешь имеют безударные окончания. Тогда при выборе спряжения по правилу мы получим II спряжение, а не I  спряжение.

**О причастии *выШИтый***

Страдательные причасти прошедшего времени образуются от основы **прошедшего**  времени с помощью суффиксов ***НН, ЕНН, Т.***

Если глагол оканчивается на ***ОТЬ*** и ***УТЬ***, то для образования причастий используется суффикс *Т*, глагольный суффикс **сохраняется**: расколоть – расколол – расколотый, перекинуть – перекинул – перекинутый.

Суффикс ***Т*** используется также для образования причастий от глаголов с основой на **корневую** гласную: ***вы/ши/ть – вы/ши/л – вы/ши/т/ый.***  Суффикс ***Т*** вместо суффикса ***Л.***

**Вывод**

Итак, правильные формы: ***вы/шь/ет, вы/ши/тый***. Но в личной форме используется окончание ***ЕТ***, а в причастии корень ***ШИ*** и суффикс ***Т.***

Comment: Очень интересно. Вам, однако, надо знать, что, во-первых, надо писать не *1-ое* и  *2-ое*, а *1-е* и *2-е*; во-вторых, мы обычно, говоря о спряжениях, используем латинские цифры: *I и II спряжение.* Очень советую прочитать правила наращений на Грамоте.ру!

Comment: Спасибо, моя невнимательность, скопироваЛА из старых записочек... А так    я знаю про наращения, даже сама правило придумала! Оно у них какое-то непонятное, а у меня –  очень хорошее, в ОДНО ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ. Если хотите – расскажу.

Comment: Очень заинтригован-с. Расскажите-таки.

Comment: Ага, сейчас, только ответ поправлю.

Comment: Очень просто! Смотрю на окончание - сколько буковок (одна, две. три). Одну не сократишь,  а от двух и трех можно по единичке отнять. Вот и получаем: 1-е, 2-е, 1-го, 2-го.  Как вам?  Критика нужна! Я нашим рассказывала, но они ничего  не поняли и слушать не стали.

Comment: Наращение на может иметь три буквы.

Comment: Две или три буквы в исходном слове. Из перв/ого класса, из 1-го класса. В перв/ом классе, в 1-м классе.

Comment: Мне, честно, делать наращения удобней просто опираясь на то, согласная или гласная перед последней буквой. Ваш способ я, однако, мисс, понял.

Comment: Thank you, sir. But it's just your habit, really. And my rule is very simple, and you won't repeat it every morning.

Comment: Ich hab mir schon so gut diese Regel gemerkt, dass ich sie niemals vergessen werde, und ich brauche sie also nicht mehr zu wiederholen.

Comment: But you could tell your friends about it, for example... Who haven't learned all this yet.

Comment: Es könnte für sie schwierig sein, zu verstehen, was die Endung jeder Zahl ist.

Comment: Könnten Sie also Deutsch?

Comment: Ich hätte schreiben sollen: „Können Sie also Deutsch?“

Comment: Нет, немецкий я не знаю (пользуюсь переводчиком). Я и английский не очень-то знаю, но перехожу на английский, чтобы изменить стилистику сообщений. Русская речь в английском варианте звучит по-особенному (для носителей русского языка). Получается  иной оттенок, и это мне нравится. К примеру,  что-то ясно откровенное в русском языке звучит вполне нейтрально и пристойно (звучит для меня, конечно, а как для англичан,  не знаю).

Comment: Теперь о Правиле сокращений. Попробую задать на эту тему вопрос — посмотрим на реакцию участников, очень любопытно! Вероятно, новаторство никому не понравится, но все-таки интересно.

Answer (score 1):

> Почему пишется не *вышетый*, а *вышитый*? Мне интересно именно
> многоохватывающее правило.

***Вы́-ш(и/е)-т-ый***.

Проблемная безударная гласная находится в корне этого слова.

**Правило** из учебника по русскому языку для 2-го класса:

> *Чтобы проверить безударный гласный в корне, необходимо изменить форму слова или подобрать такое родственное слово, чтобы проверяемый гласный
> оказался под ударением.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Родственные слову ***вышитый*** слова, в которых гласная в корне находится под ударением:

***ши́ть, сши́тый…***

— Под ударением в корне этих слов – буква «и» (не «ы»!; вспомните правило: ЖИ-ШИ пиши с буквой И).

Такая же буква И должна писаться и в однокоренном с этими словами слове ***вышитый***.